# what I've done to get ValueError in logging module python

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I want to write log to both file and stdout, Hence I use this code but I always get this ValueError in stdout but not in file.

I want logging from INFO level and above to get to both stdout and a file. and DEBUG level and above to be wrote to a file.

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(funcName)-5s %(message)s',
                    filename='OkanimeDownloader.log',
                    filemode='w')

console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname):-8s %(message)s')
console.setFormatter(formatter)
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)



dic = {'Google Drive': 'https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-fK-jS8DjCeYVVwRWdfWnc1YWs/preview', 'Mega': '//vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=359177611&id=456239042&hash=59d982cc2450bc8d&sd', 'Openload': 'https://openload.co/embed/MVysKUs5rm4/%5BOKanime.com%5D_s%40ks2_-_11_%28animok%29.mp4', 'Streamango': 'https://streamango.com/embed/pnfdsqnedcffrttm/_OKanime_com_s_ks2_-_11_animok_mp4', 'Cloudy': 'https://www.cloudy.ec/embed.php?id=09c53285b6ac4', 'Tune.pk': 'https://embed.tune.pk/play/7147555/okanimecom-sks2-11-animok', 'Mp4upload': 'https://www.mp4upload.com/embed-swz4hesaisnm.html'}

logging.info('The dic:  {}'.format(dic))
```

output:

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 992, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 838, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 578, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 547, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 391, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
ValueError: unsupported format character ':' (0x3a) at index 12
Call stack:
  File "/Users/hamza/Dropbox/My Py Projects/Okanime/testing json.py", line 18, in <module>
    logging.info('The dic:  {}'.format(dic))
Message: "The dic:  {'Google Drive': 'https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-fK-jS8DjCeYVVwRWdfWnc1YWs/preview', 'Mega': '//vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=359177611&id=456239042&hash=59d982cc2450bc8d&sd', 'Openload': 'https://openload.co/embed/MVysKUs5rm4/%5BOKanime.com%5D_s%40ks2_-_11_%28animok%29.mp4', 'Streamango': 'https://streamango.com/embed/pnfdsqnedcffrttm/_OKanime_com_s_ks2_-_11_animok_mp4', 'Cloudy': 'https://www.cloudy.ec/embed.php?id=09c53285b6ac4', 'Tune.pk': 'https://embed.tune.pk/play/7147555/okanimecom-sks2-11-animok', 'Mp4upload': 'https://www.mp4upload.com/embed-swz4hesaisnm.html'}"
Arguments: ()
```

Comment: You can't have it in the log file because it's the act of trying to put it in the log file that's causing the error. That said, I'm really not sure why the logging module is unhappy with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)-8s : %(message)s')
```

This syntax fix the error in the Formatter

Comment: Oh good catch. It's probably best to elaborate though on what happened.

Comment: @roganjosh i'm digging into the source now, probably the ":" causes parsing error in the style. any help is welcome !

Comment: I'm on my phone atm. Will look when home if still unsolved sorry